# Cannot push Vue CLI app to github.io after build - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, vue-cli-3

I've troubleshooted https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

> 1. Should the sudo command be used with Git?

I'm not using sudo together with my git commands

> 2. Check that you are connecting to the correct server

Running `$ ssh -vT git@github.com` makes the connection on port 22 and returns `You've successfully authenticated`

> 3. Always use the "git" user

I've used the set-url command to change the repo to use the SSH protocol and `ssh -T git@github.com` returns:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/warwick/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-17f81433
debug1: no match: babeld-17f81433
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/warwick/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XUyMmE8J489MaD9Ix/1xJdilSU4aH/F27hdhQubMQL4
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XUyMmE8J489MaD9Ix/1xJdilSU4aH/F27hdhQubMQL4
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XUyMmE8J489MaD9Ix/1xJdilSU4aH/F27hdhQubMQL4
Enter passphrase for key '/home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.118.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_ZA.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi WNortier! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3452, received 2484 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6930.1, received 4986.7
debug1: Exit status 1
```

> 4. Make sure you have a key that is being used

I've created a new public/private key combination as per https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account
`Identity added: /home/warwick/.ssh/id_rsa (myemail@gmail.com)`

**There is a problem here:**

Starting `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in the terminal and running `ssh-add -l` is returning `The agent has no identities.` even though I just added it?

*Pushing changes made to the project src files to github does not prompt me for my password and when I check my github settings I see the key is used. So the key appears to be working*

I run into Permission denied (publickey) every time I try to run build and push. I created a .deploy.sh file as per this guide on the Vue documentation and uncommented and added my username on the line intended for a github.io push https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

```
set -e
npm run build
cd dist
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "deploy"
git push -f git@github.com:wnortier/wnortier.github.io.git master
cd -
```

but when I run it with `sh .deploy.sh` it returns

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2175ms                                  15:40:48
  File                                 Size               Gzipped

  dist/js/chunk-vendors.c4d3d4de.js    114.27 KiB         40.31 KiB
  dist/js/app.8b5fd9c9.js              6.99 KiB           2.90 KiB
  dist/css/app.35dcd38a.css            0.27 KiB           0.21 KiB

  Images and other types of assets omitted.

 DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/warwick/Projects/wnortier.github.io/dist/.git/
[master (root-commit) 74551eb] deploy
 8 files changed, 14 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 css/app.35dcd38a.css
 create mode 100644 favicon.ico
 create mode 100644 img/logo.82b9c7a5.png
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 js/app.8b5fd9c9.js
 create mode 100644 js/app.8b5fd9c9.js.map
 create mode 100644 js/chunk-vendors.c4d3d4de.js
 create mode 100644 js/chunk-vendors.c4d3d4de.js.map
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

git config is as follows:

```
user.email=warwick.nortier@gmail.com
user.name=warwick
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/WNortier/wnortier.github.io.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=warwick
user.email=warwick.nortier@gmail.com
```

Please could anyone assist me?

Comment: 1. Could you include the contents of your git config file (.git/config) and .deploy.sh for the repo?

2. Could you include full verbose output of npm run build?

Comment: You're authenticating as a GH user `WNortier`. You can now push to any repository under https://github.com/WNortier or to any GH repository for which `WNortier` has been added as a collaborator. To which repo are you trying to push? This one, I suppose: https://github.com/WNortier/wnortier.github.io ?

Comment: @chrisputnam9 I added it to the bottom of my post

Comment: @phd correct its my own repo

Comment: Can you push to the repo from the command line?

Comment: @phd yes I can push any changes made to the project, but its blocking me when I try to run my script which contains the build command... I've tried running all the commands in the script manually using sudo but also said permission denied

Comment: `sudo` is the culprit, of course. It changes the current user and `git` (`ssh` to be precise) don't have access to your ssh keys. Never use `sudo` unless it's really required (sysadmin tasks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my ssh key was setup correctly all along.
I've managed to solve the problem by running the following command: `sudo chown -R $USERNAME /home/<myusername>`
It allowed me to run the deploy script without [sudo].

Answer (score 1):

Set the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` in your session (as you, not root)

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

And run your script.

You will see the same kind of debug log you have in your question.
If not, that means the script is not running with your profile environment settings, which could explain why it works in command-line when done manually, and not through said script.